# GDI+ acceleration

Tags: gdi+, graphic, hardware-acceleration

This might be a dumb question but when I use GDI+ is it automatically GPU hardware accelerated?
E.g. is this the case for the following code?

```
g = pbCanvas.CreateGraphics();
PointF P1 = ...
PointF P2 = ...
g.DrawLine(pen1, P1, P2);
```

Thanx for the help!

Comment: I do not believe that any of the geometric drawing is GPU accelerated - ["..the GPU can accelerate these updates to the video memory surface. For example, *text rendering, BitBlts, AlphaBlend, TransparentBlt, and StretchBlt are all accelerated* in these cases.. In order to maintain compatibility, GDI performs a large part of its *rendering to aperture memory using the CPU* .. *In contrast,* Direct2D translates its APIs calls into Direct3D primitives and drawing operations.."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: As far as I know now GDI+ has taken the place of GDI since Win95. By looking on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface I get this:    GDI+ adds anti-aliased 2D graphics, floating point coordinates, gradient shading, more complex path management, intrinsic support for modern graphics-file formats like JPEG and PNG, and support for composition of affine transformations in the 2D view pipeline. GDI+ uses ARGB values to represent color. So if GDI+ adds support for affine composition why should it add support for line segments?!?!?

Comment: It isn't that it "shouldn't" it is because it *doesn't*- the 'Why not?' question is a discussion question but "In order to maintain compatibility.." may be a sufficient justification in and of itself.

Comment: Sorry for the typo I meant ... .why shoudn't it add support for line segments?!?